# Haskell quickCheck - grab and modify the generated parameters

Tags: haskell

I wrote an encryption and decryption functions with the following function types:

```
encrypt::[Char]->[Char]->[Char]
decrypt::[Char]->[Char]->[Char]
```

These functions are tested out manually and work correctly. The only thing is that they work on capital letters ONLY.

I also wrote a test property function, which via the above 2 functions encrypts a `mssg` and decrypts its encryption. Then it compares the decryption to `mssg` to ensure that all works fine. `m` stands for mssg and `k` stands for key.

```
test::[Char]->[Char]->Bool
test [] []          = True
test m k            = m == (decrypt (encrypt m k) k)
```

Now I want to use quickCheck on test to randomly generate the message and key. This is for automating testing.

```
main = print $ quickCheck test
```

However, quickCheck will produce lower-case letters as well and I don't want that. I want to be able to modify the parameters generated by quickCheck to only include capital-letters. How can I do that?

Comment: is this related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30428408/haskell-quickcheck-generate-non-upper) ?

Comment: no. I have nothing to do with that question.

Comment: maybe you have the same teacher? - well anyway - Joes answer is not that bad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as JosEduSol only gave a very incomplete answer I'll try to help you out a bit more.

First have a look at the code:

```
module Test where

import Test.QuickCheck

newtype OnlyUpper = OU String
                  deriving Show

encrypt :: String -> String -> String
encrypt _ msg = reverse msg

decrypt :: String -> String -> String
decrypt _ msg = reverse msg

test :: OnlyUpper -> OnlyUpper -> Bool
test (OU msg) (OU key) = msg == (decrypt key . encrypt key) msg

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck test

instance Arbitrary OnlyUpper where
  arbitrary = fmap OU $ listOf $ choose ('A', 'Z')
```

as you can see I choose a very dumb implementation for `encrypt` and `decrpyt` (and I switched the arguments for convenience).

Also I removed the error in your `main` (no need to `print`).

The important part is: I introduced a `newtype OnlyUpper` and I made it an instance of `Arbitrary` - this way *QuickCheck* knows what to do with it (generate lists of only upper characters)

In order for your tests to use it you now of course have to accept arguments of type `OnlyUpper` to work with (I changed your one test accordingly) - just deconstruct it on the spot (`(OU msg)`) and the rest should really be the same.

Maybe you don't know what the `fmap` is all about here - then thing is that `Arbitrary` is a functor and `listOf $ choose ('A', 'Z')` will *give you* lists of characters between `'A'` and `'Z'` - but you have to wrap this into `OU` so you get `OnlyUpper` back (instead of `[Char]`) - that's what the `fmap OU` is doing here.

Comment: makes good sense. Could you provide a bit further insight on how fmap works?